# Looking for an android kmz / kmz app viewer with gps support

Tags: android, gps, offline

I have some KMZ files of cadastral maps. I need to fiscally go to the boundaries of my lands (parcels) and take a look at where they are with the gps and maps support.
Some of these places are not covered by the phone network signal.

For this reason I'm looking for an android app that will import my kmz files and let me reach the boundaries position with gps support.

I've used google earth app, but gps position is not working.

Google maps engine app, instead, works well but only with online maps.

Any idea on an app to work offline?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12452/list-of-gis-applications-for-android-tablets/80580#80580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use **[Locus Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus)** with things like that. On my request, *menion* (the author) implemented support for full offline `.kmz` – i.e. the `.kmz` files can be self-contained, including everything like images etc., and then are available with all their data, not requiring any network connection. That's an ideal thing to create your own travel guide, which I did a couple of times.

There are several addons available for *Locus Maps*, a.o. an "Augmented Reality" addon – which can be used to see in which direction there might be something interesting which you "bookmarked" (have an entry in one of your `.kmz` files) – in your case this can be handy when checking what's in sight, visually.

[image: Locus Maps] [image: Locus Maps] [image: Locus Maps]
<sup>*Locus Maps:* Ranges, NAvigation, Compass (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

Pretty good support, regular updates, privacy-first (if you want to navigate your contacts, you either have to enter their addresses manually, or need a separate addon – *Locus Maps* itself avoids requesting permissions with privacy concerns). Supports a range of features by itself, like Navigation, Geocaching, and much more. You can create your own waypoints, and later export them as `.kml` (or your track as `.gpx`) – a feature you might welcome when walking your boundaries.