# Take GPS coordinates+pictures+memo of a point of interest, on offline Android

Tags: android, note-taking, offline, gps

Sometimes I find a great restaurant and think "*I should add it to [Wikivoyage](http://wikivoyage.org) when I have time*".

So I am looking for a way to very quickly:

- Save the GPS coordinate of my current position
- Let me take a few pictures if I want
- Let me write a memo if I want

The association between the 3 should be remembered. The Android app does not have to show me a map or anything, actually no map might be better, since I will be using it in countries where I have no Internet connection.

When I come back home I should be able to see the 3 details of each point of interest I took. Ideally on a map, but a text file is enough.

Requirements:

- Free
- Usable offline
- Runs on Android
- Launches very fast, minimalist UI
- When I come back home I should be able to use the data on Linux

Strongly preferred:

- Does not require [Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191875/google-play-services-how-to-handle-devices-that-do-not-have-google-play)
- Does not require network/contacts permissions
- Open source

Comment: Plenty of solutions, Nicolas! Which one to chose depends on whether above described is all you want to cover. There are [Location based Memos](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=128) (note the photo-specific section), there's [Trip Mapping](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=131), and there is [Locus Maps](http://www.appbrain.com/app/menion.android.locus), which lets you add your own POIs with photo(s) and export them as KML, easy to process on any OS. Which direction you wanna go?

Comment: @Izzy: Nice website! I added a few requirements. SpotMarker, Mark Photo Spot, Map it! do not seem to be usable offline. TapTag is free 30-day trial. Trying ViewRanger GPS now.

Comment: Thanks – glad you like my site! If offline is an requirement, *Locus Maps* might be a good fit. From above list, that's the only one I have experience with, using it always on vacation for "navigation/orientation" (offline maps) and "recording" POIs as you've described above. Might be a little overkill if you want to record POIs *only*, which is why I didn't make it an answer straight ahead. No contacts permission either: menion is pretty privacy aware, for contacts, *Locus* needs an addon :) Not FOSS, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**OSMtracker**](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSMtracker_%28Android%29). It is specifically designed for surveying for OpenStreetMap, which is pretty similar to what you want to do.

It can record a GPS track, plus you can add text notes, or voice recording, or take a photo. It also has shortcuts for marking specific types of points of interest, eg hotels, restaurants etc. It is very fast, with minimalist UI - as standard it doesn't show any maps. So it works fine offline.

[image: OSMTracker screenshot]

It can export to a GPX file, which will include all of the points and photos etc that you have marked. So there is a variety of software for using GPX files on Linux, and viewing on a map etc.

It is free and open source, licensed as GPLv3. The permissions seem pretty minimal, contacts permission not required. It only uses the network for showing the track on a map, or uploading direct to OpenStreetMap, both of which are optional. It can be installed from Google Code if you don't want to use Google Play.

Comment: Having to wait for the GPS fix to start entering POI details is a major inconvenience. The best time to enter details is when I am in the restaurant, but usually within the restaurant there is no GPS visibility.

Comment: Also, it insists on capturing a "track", so I am forced to go through a "list of tracks" screen everytime. I don't want to save a track, only amenities.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, have you checked [my suggestions](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9881/185)? Seem to answer these two points: a) enter your description whenever you want, correct the POIs location later (if needed), and 2) POI!=Track (with Locus you can have both, but it's separate items).

Answer (score 3):

**[Locus Maps](http://www.appbrain.com/app/menion.android.locus)** is a candidate capable of this (and of many other things). For some details, you might wish to take a look at my other answers recommending this app:

- [Offline map browser on Android with offline search](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/277/185)
- [Looking for an android kmz / kmz app viewer with gps support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7574/185)
- [App for Android that reads Open Street Map data but can be used as a GPS or for Directions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/273/185)

With the first two containing some screenshots. Here are some more, covering your specific request:

[image: Locus menu] [image: select attachment]
<sup>*Locus Maps:* Add a POI / Attach media</sup>

Long-pressing on a location opens a context menu, and lets you add a POI. You can write a description, and even attach media (not only photos, you could also place an audio note when too lazy to type).

*Locus Maps* is designed for outdoor activities, so off course it is able to work completely offline (though you can use online maps as well). Map sources are plenty, including e.g. OSM and Google Maps. Tons of addons available for more features (Geocaching and Augmented Reality, just to name two).

Concerning privacy: *Locus Maps* itself doesn't request access to your contacts. So if you're one who wants to directly navigate to addresses from your contacts list, you would need to explicitely install the contacts addon.

Referring to your requirements explicitely:

- **Free:** It has two free versions: one is free of charge, the other free of ads ;) On the project site, you can [compare their features](http://www.locusmap.eu/features/compare-versions/).
- **Usable offline:** Definitely (both versions)
- **Runs on Android:** Yes, AFAIK only there.
- **Launches very fast, minimalist UI:** Depends on what you call fast/minimalist, and on your hardware specs. A good compromise it is, but offering many features it's for sure not "absolutely minimalist"
- **When I come back home I should be able to use the data on Linux:** No problem, that's what I do (my only windows are those for light and fresh air). It can read/write e.g. GPX, KML, KMZ – at least the latter format (KMZ) should be suitable for your case, containing data, desc, and media
- **Does not require Google Play Services:** The paid version relies on Google Licensing. But speaking to the dev, there might be a way around that as well
- **Does not require network/contacts permissions:** No contacts permission, as described. Network is of course needed for maps and route planning, but it works well without a network connection: If you didn't download maps beforehand, well, then you get an empty grid (and mybe unable to tell where *exactly* you want to place your mark)
- **Open Source:** unfortunately not.

---

Naming an alternative:

[image: Trip Journal] [image: Report]
<sup>Trip Journal: Main screen, report (source: Izzy)</sup>

**[Trip Journal](http://www.appbrain.com/app/trip-journal-lite/com.iqapps.mobile.tripjournallite)** is made for that purpose explicitely. You write your travel journal while on the road, and send reports before getting home. Works offline as well (with or without maps pre-cached), no Open Source, but a free and a paid version. Outputs to KMZ, but quite a heavy-weight variant with lots of JavaScript and stuff, so it only works with *Google Earth*. I can provide a How-To on converting that into a more light-weight variant (I figured out myself), but I'm not sure if it's still valid with their latest versions. Still, might be worth a look.

Differences to *Locus Maps* concerning your requirements: requires contacts permission.